# Receiving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when adding library to UIAutomator project using Android Studio built with Gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-uiautomator

Im trying to add Joda-Time as a dependency to my UIAutomator test project in Android Studio using Gradle and I get the following error when I try to use the LocalDate class in Joda:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.LocalDate
```

Im not sure what Im doing wrong.  Im pretty sure my build.gradle and Test Class is correct.  This probably isnt a Joda problem...Im just implementing the library wrong.

Here is my gradle.properties:

```
androidSdkHome=/Users/timbo/sdk
androidSdkTarget=android-20
androidSdkBuildToolsDir=build-tools/android-4.4W/
```

Heres my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

version = '0.1'

project.ext {
    dexDir = new File('build/dex')
    distDir = new File('./dist')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: androidSdkHome + '/platforms/' + androidSdkTarget, include: '*.jar')
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.5'
}

jar {
    doLast {
        tasks.dex.execute()
    }
}

task dex(dependsOn: jar, type:Exec) {
    println 'Building dex...'
    project.dexDir.mkdirs()
    workingDir '.'
    commandLine androidSdkHome + '/' + androidSdkBuildToolsDir + '/' + 'dx', '--dex', '--no-strict', '--output=' + buildDir +'/dex/' + project.name + '.jar', jar.archivePath
    doLast {
        tasks.dist.execute()
    }
}

task dist(dependsOn:dex, type:Copy) {
    project.distDir.mkdirs()
    from(project.dexDir)
    into(project.distDir)
    include('*.jar')
}
```

Here is my Test:

```
package com.mofo.hilton.android.uiautomator.tests;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

/**
 * Created by TimBo on 10/11/14.
 */
public class TestJodaTime extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {


    }

    public void testJodaTime() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

        LocalDate dt = new LocalDate();
        LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = dt.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
        System.out.println(lastDayOfMonth);

    }
}
```

And here is an image of the External libraries that are in my project:

[image: external libraries in AS]

Comment: Is there any missing information from my question?  Could someone please help?

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this problem? I am facing the same challenge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494313/android-api-19-jodatime-org-joda-time-localdateproperty-not-found

Comment: Yes....due to the nature of how uiautomator runs which is in an adb shell on the device, you cannot include any 3rd party libraries unless they themselves were supported by uiautomator or could be executed in an adb shell.